# appendRow() in google apps script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I use `appendRow()` to set values in "Sheet1" and use it again to set values to "Sheet2" but this time, it should start at cell "A10" and stop at "A30". They both have the same contents. Are there any other ways aside from `appendRow()`?

Answer (score 0):

You might be misunderstanding how `Sheet.appendRow` works. It will always insert the values in the first row after the data range. If you need to add values on a specific cell / range, instead use `Range.setValues`. Bear in mind that `Sheet.appendRow` requires an Array representing a row where each element corresponds to one column, while `Range.setValues` requires an Array of Arrays, where the outer Array elements represents one row and the inner Arrays elements are the cells corresponding to each column of the row.

Example:

```
function writeValues(){
  const rowValues = [1,2,3];
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  const sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sheet1.getRange(10,1,1,3).setValues([rowValues]);
  
  const sheet2 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  sheet2.getRange(30,1,1,3).setValues([rowValues]);

}
```